# Pick random tensors from another one in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Tensor X whith shape [B, L, E] (let's say, B batches of L vectors of length E). From this Tensor X, I want to randomly pick N vectors in each batch, and so create Y with shape [B, N, E].

I tried to combine tf.random_uniform and tf.gather but I really struggle with the dimension and can't get Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

B = 3
L = 5
E = 2
N = 3

input = np.array(range(B * L * E)).reshape([B, L, E])
print(input)
print("#################################")

X = tf.constant(input)
batch_range = tf.tile(tf.reshape(tf.range(B, dtype=tf.int32), shape=[B, 1, 1]), [1, N, 1])
random = tf.random_uniform([B, N, 1], minval = 0, maxval = L - 1, dtype = tf.int32)

indices = tf.concat([batch_range, random], axis = 2)

output = tf.gather_nd(X, indices)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(indices))
    print("#################################")
    print(sess.run(output))
```